# How can we create a user with Firebase Auth in node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create user account using Firebase auth in nodejs. It doesn't work and I don't know why. Here's the code and the error generated by nodejs:

```
var config = {.......}; // i can't share the config

var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);

var db = app.database();
var auth = app.auth();

auth.createUserWithUsernameAndPassword("anemail@gmail.com", "@NewPassWord").then(
    function(user){ console.log(user);},
    function(error){ console.error(error);}
);
```

Error generate by NodeJS:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'createUserWithUsernameAndPassword'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/antonio/Projects/firebase/app.js:20:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: I have this exact same problem! Please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504466/firebase-auth-createuserwithemailandpassword-undefined-is-not-a-function?lq=1

Comment: I have found a work-around for this using anonymous user authentication from the client side. Kindly elaborate your use case, so that I could write an answer based on that.

Answer (score 5):

I finally got it working in Node.js. Is your `app` an instance of `firebase-admin` by any chance, as opposed to `firebase`?

In my `express` app I initialise `firebase` in the main `app.js` like so (pretty standard fare):

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

firebase.initializeApp
({
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  databaseURL: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx"
});
```

Then in the `route` responsible for creating users I do this:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next)
{
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword
  (
    email,
    password
  )
  .then(function(userRecord)
  {
    res.location('/user/' + userRecord.uid);
    res.status(201).end();
  })
  .catch(function(error)
  {
    res.write
    ({
      code: error.code
    });
    res.status(401).end();
  });
});
```

Comment: Where do you handle the login or authentication of a user in express?

Answer (score 3):

well, I don't think that the method `"createUserWithUsernameAndPassword"` works,

Use this instead `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

you used username when firebase use email

Answer (score 3):

As of May 2017, this is what we are using successfully.

```
  // Create the authenticated user
  admin.auth().createUser({
    email: email,
    password: password,
    displayName: `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: This isn't an answer but is extending [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43947493/7098234) answer by @Gregg above.

I too was struggling to create users using an service account with Firebase + node + express.

For anyone else interested:

In the root `app.js` I have:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: "https://<app-name>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

and in the auth.js route I have (as per @Gregg):

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

firebase.auth().defaultAuth.createUser({
  email: req.body.email,
  password: req.body.password,
  displayName: req.body.username,
})
```

I know this is only a slight extension to the earlier answer however the docs seem to be very unclear, and I've noticed a large number of people that have the same or similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cyrus' response is correct.

However, please note that as of Nov 2016 the way to do this is the following:

```
firebaseAdmin.auth().createUser({
    email: "user@example.com",
    password: "secretPassword"
  })
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // A UserRecord representation of the newly created user is returned
    console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
  });
```

See a more complete guide in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user).