# firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following the firebase documentation on user management

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
    serviceAccount: "./<mysecreturledittedout>.json",
    databaseURL: "https://<mydatabaseurljusttobesafe>.firebaseio.com"
});

router.get('/create', function(req, res){
    var email = req.email;
    var password = req.password;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(err){ // LINE 27 CRASH
        var errorCode = err.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
    });
});
```

I get the following error

```
undefined is not a function

TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at d:\Users\Kitty\Code\Practice2\routes\index.js:27:21
```

From doing a little bit of research, I think undefined is not a function is basically a javascript version of a null pointer exception (could be wrong)

I have configured my service account and project on firebase. I am running this on localhost. Thanks. I am looking primarily for debugging tips, as I'm not sure how to test what isn't working.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485998/how-can-we-create-a-user-with-firebase-auth-in-node-js (has no answer yet).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Apologies, did not see that question yet.

Comment: I have found a work-around for this using anonymous user authentication from the client side. Kindly elaborate your use case, so that I could write an answer based on that.

Comment: @NiwinSanthosh Hi, thanks for your input. What ended up happening was I dumped nodejs server side code entirely to structure my web app and use firebase static hosting. Using static web auth was easier for me. Since asking this, however, I've been looking back into server side because I want to send custom emails but firebase has deprecated this functionality :( .

Comment: I think it would be possible if we create an anonymous user in firebase from client side and do all backend tasks with Node JS. Then once the backend process is over, send back the username and password to link it in the client side using the previously created anonymous user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813062/firebase-create-user-on-node-js-server/39596386#39596386

Answer (score 6):

If you haven't fixed the problem yet, I found out why it's giving such an error and that's because it really isn't a function.

You're using the Web reference as your guide when you need to be using the Server reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth.

As you can see, firebase.auth.Auth is a lot different on the Node.js API when compared to the Web API as there's not a lot in there. Now you have to deal with tokens, which I haven't looked deep into, if using the Server API. On the other hand, you can just use the Web API, which does things you intended to do.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**
Sometime at or before firebase 3.4.1 for Node.js, `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` became available.

**Original**
As of firebase 3.1.0 for Node.js, `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is not yet supported. According to a response on the firebase Google group, not all platforms have feature parity in the 3.x libraries yet. The REST interface does support user creation but is clearly a different approach than using the Node.js library.

Go to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk and search for createUserWithEmailAndPassword for the latest on that discussion.

Comment: The REST API does not support user creation anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027535/how-to-createuser-using-firebase-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is correct, but it helps:

1. In  console.firebase.google.com get 
   script:

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

and Config:

```js
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "project-nnnnnnnnnnn.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project-nnnnnnnnnnn.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "project-nnnnnnnnnnn.appspot.com",
};
```

2. Copy firebase.js file from

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

to  local project fb/firebase.js

3. In firebas-service.ts:

```js
    var firebase = require('./fb/firebase');
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "project-nnnnnnnnnnn.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project-nnnnnnnnnnn.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "project-nnnnnnnnnnn.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

export function createUser (email : string, password:string){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        if (error.code){
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            alert(errorMessage);
            console.log(errorMessage);
        }
        else{
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Using catch I can use a callback to handle errors, but how I can execute JS code when the registration was successful? Edit: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511285/firebase-v3-createuserwithemailandpassword-then-promise

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because you defined the error as "err", but under errorMessage, "error.message" was the code? Not quite sure, but try this and see if it fixes:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
    serviceAccount: "./<mysecreturledittedout>.json",
    databaseURL: "https://<mydatabaseurljusttobesafe>.firebaseio.com"
});

router.get('/create', function(req, res){
    var email = req.email;
    var password = req.password;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error){ 
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry that did not fix the problem. I changed all of them to `err`. Thanks for your time

Answer (score -1):

Question is old and I didn't see any accepted answer. And for the other people who still face the same problem. This is what I did to resolve my issue.

- Remove the node_modules
- Remove the firebase from package.json and
  install the latest firebase `npm install --save firebase`
- And run npm install once again so that all other dependencies also get
  installed

After that add

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/firestore");
require("firebase/auth");
```

Whatever module you want to use in your project, you can mentioned accordingly. Then initialise the firebase

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXXX.COM",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXXXX"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Later you can write your API to create user with email and password

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    var emailId = req.email
    var password = req.password;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailId, password).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      console.log(error)
    });

})
```