# firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged not firing with Authorized domains

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {...})` on the firebase Node SDK works perfectly on localhost and I use it for mission critical setting uid in my Redux store etc, but it is not firing on my live domains at all even though I have added them to Authorized domains in the Auth control panel.

This is breaking some fairly significant things in my site, any ideas why its not doing its thing?

I am using email, facebook and google auth providers.

it is like this question [firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603118/firebase-auth-onauthstatechanged-not-working) except that his solution doesn't work.

Comment: How should we have any idea from what you have provided us with?

Comment: Are you using OAuth providers like Google and FB?

Comment: Yes both, sorry there just isn't any more information - onAuthStateChanged just isn't firing when auth state changes on Authorized domains. I may have to try contacting firebase support or just not using it - I can use the data auth puts in localStorage and the callback with the user object from login success instead, I guess, it was just convenient.

Comment: Does it only happen for OAuth providers or email as well? When you try to login in with Google, does it redirect to google's account chooser page? And are there any errors printed in dev console?

Comment: Try setting  a value for the error and end callback of `onAuthStateChanged`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your domain name in the credential list of your OAuth2.0 Web client using this link console.cloud.google.com. Make sure that you added your domain over there to...then your domain accepts that OAuth client key then it will work fine, its works for me.

Once you added please wait for 5 mins or sometimes it might take more than that too....but it will work