# Firebase auth gets stuck on iOS login without error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've set up the most basic implementation of firebase auth login with email and password.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {

    console.log('Logged in')
    window.location.href = "./home.html"

}).catch(function (error) {

    console.log(error)

});
```

For some reason, on iOS, the login process sometimes gets stuck waiting for the promise of signInWithEmailAndPassword() to resolve. I don't get any error message.

The only way to re-enable the login mechanism is to clear the browser cache.

Is this a known problem? I've been experiencing this problem for my last two apps over the last year.

**Edit:** After further trial and error I found out that the problem usually happens after being logged in, letting the iPhone go to sleep, waking it back up, and then logging out. Then the same problem also happens for the signOut() function.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, and explain in more detail.

Comment: If you think there is a bug, and you're able to reproduce it with specific steps, you should file a bug report with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Ok Doug, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem had to do with the domain not being whitelisted in my project settings. The reason why I didn't pay attention to the console alert about oAuth was that it did work most of the times, even with it showing. So I thought it didn't have any effect on it.

The answer was suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603118/firebase-auth-onauthstatechanged-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, but it was even more consistent when I moved to **version 9** of the firebase sdk and my app was running in an **Ionic-Capacitor native app on iOS**. The solution was to add "localhost" to Firebase > Authentication > Sign-in method > Authorize domains (NOTE: if you use localhost make sure you have sufficient security db rules to prevent someone from adding bad data and you may not want to use this in production).

Then I needed to use **intializeAuth() when running in hybrid (native app) mode**. My app is also a pwa and getAuth(app) makes assumptions that its loading in a browser environment which causes this problem.

```
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(FirebaseConfig);
this.firebaseAuth = isPlatform('hybrid') ? 
    initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence}) :
    this.firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
```

Comment: While this was not marked as the correct solution, I had the exact same problem and changing the way I set up my Auth object as you have suggested solved this for me. Thank you!

Comment: i have this same problem with my ionic-capacitor angular project,  if this is  the solution,  how can i implement this in my angular 17 standalone project as i get the following error after i tried to use your method to solve the problem:   ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/already-initialized).
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/already-initialized).

Comment: White-listing or setting the authorized domain as localhost is only relevant if your project is operating from within a native mobile app through something like Capacitor or in a development environment.  If you are running your angular project from a particular website, you may need to set your authorized domain to be the website where your angular project is running.

Comment: The problem was solved when i added thee following to my maint.ts:

provideFirebaseApp(() => {
        const app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
        if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
          initializeFirestore(app, {
            localCache: persistentLocalCache(),
          });
          initializeAuth(app, {
            persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
          });
        }
        return app;
      }),

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when i added thee following to my maint.ts:

```
provideFirebaseApp(() => {
    const app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
        if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
          initializeFirestore(app, {
        localCache: persistentLocalCache(),
      });
      initializeAuth(app, {
        persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
      });
    }
    return app;
  }),
```