# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword method is undefined in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

There is a problem in starting..

I initialized my firebase app. But auth() is not working

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
console.log(auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword)
```

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns undefined.

It also gives function error

```
var email = "mail@mail.com"
var password = 123

var auth = firebase.auth();
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result)
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

The error:

> TypeError: auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

What is the problem?

Comment: are you initializing your app with `firebase.initializeApp(config);`?

Comment: Yes, I use initializeApp. firebase.database is working, but firebase.auth isn't working

Comment: What is your version in package.json? Firebase had major change few weeks ago. Maybe you need to update to new 3.x version or go back to 2.x

Comment: @libik I am using version 3.0.5

Comment: *firebaser here* There is no functionality to create users in the 3.0 version of the Firebase SDK for Node.js. We're working on it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504466/firebase-auth-createuserwithemailandpassword-undefined-is-not-a-function?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method createUserWithEmailAndPassword in Firebase 3.0.5 for node.js, look at [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#verifyIdToken)

Comment: 3.3.x has it now. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/39596386/432311